# How do you connect shader node with shader group?

Tags: python

Hello I am currently trying to make an addon that involves connecting the shader node and the group. This is how I am approaching it however it returns a AttributeError referring node group as 'NoneType'. How can I connect shader nodes and node groups?

```
mat = bpy.context.object.active_material
mat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = mat.node_tree

nodeGroup = node_tree.nodes.get("Shader group") #Shader group
nodeDF = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage') #Shader node

node_tree.links.new(nodeGroup.inputs[0], nodeDF.outputs[0]) #Connecting the nodes
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inputs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add a group to node_tree and connect the slot

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.context.object.active_material
mat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = mat.node_tree

group = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
group.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['Shader group']

nodeDF = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage') #Shader node

node_tree.links.new(group.inputs[0], nodeDF.outputs[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!